# NFC not working

Tags: qt, nfc

I am deploying an application on Nexus 7 tablet and also tried on Nexus 5 which supports NFC.

I am stuck here as my application in debug mode tells me that NFC is not available.

Here is my code :

```
manager = new QNearFieldManager(this);
 if(manager->isAvailable())
   {
     qDebug() << " Nfc is availiable";
   }
   else
   {
    qDebug() << " Nfc is not availiable";
    qWarning() << "NFC not available";
   }

 manager->setTargetAccessModes(QNearFieldManager::NdefReadTargetAccess);
 manager->registerNdefMessageHandler(this, SLOT(handleNdefMessage(QNdefMessage,QNearFieldTarget*)));
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(targetDetected(QNearFieldTarget*)),this,SLOT(nfcTargetDetected(QNearFieldTarget*)));

connect(manager,SIGNAL(targetLost(QNearFieldTarget*)),this, SLOT(nfcTargetLost(QNearFieldTarget*)));

if (!manager->startTargetDetection()) {
        qWarning() << "NFC target detection could not be started";
    }
```

My pro file contents:

```
QT       += core gui nfc
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = NFC_Research
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp 

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you request the NFC permission in AndroidManifext.xml?

Comment: Yes, i did add content to provide access for NFC in  AndroidManifest file. Below is the content for getting acces to NFC                                                                              <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>                                                                                  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>